# Circliful Plugin not working within ng repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use circliful(a jquery plugin https://longren.io/circliful-a-jquery-plugin-providing-animated-progress-circles/) to create a bunch of graphs within an ng repeat. However it isn't working . Will circliful not work when used within an ng repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types">
   <div>
       <div id="myStat" data-dimension="300" data-text="{{type.value}}" data-info="" data-type="half"    data-width="40" data-fontsize="38" data-percent="35" data-fgcolor="#61a9dc" data-bgcolor="#eee" data-fill="#fff" data-total="200" data-part="35" data-icon="long-arrow-up" data-icon-size="28" data-icon-color="#fff"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a directive as an attribute and triggering the circliful function on the element using the directive.

This is my markup

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types">
 <div data-text="{{type.value}}" data-type="half" chart></div>
</div>
```

This is my directive

```
app.directive('chart', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
        $timeout(function () {
            element.circliful()
        }, 100);
    }
};
});
```

The timeout is so that the chart is not drawn before the value is set.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will have multiple IDs attribute with the same ID #myStat and its wrong.

Secondly, you will have to call $('#myStat').circliful(); right after AngularJS renders your div#myStat ..

to achieve the wanted behaviour in a cool way, you will have to create a  angular directive this way :

```js
var template = '<div data-text="{{$scope.value}}"></div>';
angular.directive('Circful', function() {
  return {
    scope:{
       value : '='
    }
    restrict: 'E',
    template: myTemplate
    link : function(scope,element){
      element.circliful()
    }
  };
});
```

and use it like :

```html
<div ng-repeat="type in types">
   <div>
       <Circful value="type.value">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey this doesn't seem to render the gauge, i'm not hitting any errors but it isn't working. Do i have to specify anything within the template?.

Also i'm trying to log the values within my directive,it seems like the control isn't going to the directive.

Comment: Okay so now the gauge is getting rendered, but when i try to set the value like you've shown. I'm getting this error : [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Btype.value%7D%7D&p4=%7Btype.value%7D%7D)

Comment: try <Circful value="type.value">

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I tried above answears and ended up with this markup.

This is my directive

```
var myTemplate = '<div data-text="{{$scope.value}}"></div>';
var percentage = {};

angular.module('MyApp')
.directive('circful', function() {
    return {
      scope:{
         value : '='
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      template: myTemplate,
      link : function(scope,element){
        percentage.animationStep = 5;
        percentage.foregroundColor = '#ff6600';
        percentage.backgroundColor = '#eceaeb';
        percentage.fontColor = '#2A3440';
        percentage.foregroundBorderWidth = 35;
        percentage.backgroundBorderWidth = 35;
        percentage.pointSize = 100;
        percentage.percent = scope.value;
        element.circliful(percentage);
      }
    };
  });
```

and this is how my ng-repeat looks like

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types">
   <div>
       <circful value="type.value">
   </div>
</div>
```